# Blockproc to Average an Image

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to average the values of a MxN block in an image and replace that block with a MxN matrix with the average value. Using blockproc my code looks like:

```
a = imread('image.jpg');
fun = @(x) mean(x)*ones(size(x));
b = blockproc(a, [M N], fun);
```

However, I keep generating images that are smaller in dimension than the original (which I thought would be circumvented by utilizing ones(size(x))). In addition, the generated image is blank. Any tips on what I'm making a mistake on?

Answer (score 0):

use  [mean2](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/mean2.html) for matrix.
change fun as [example](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/blockproc.html) to

```
fun = @(block_struct) ...
mean2(block_struct.data) * ones(size(block_struct.data));
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/images/distinct-block-processing.html#f7-12949) mentions that you should use partial padding:

```
b = blockproc(a, [M N], ...
    @(block_struct) mean(block_struct.data(:)) * ones(block_struct.blockSize), ...
    'PadPartialBlocks',true);
```

Comment: The returned matrix is the correct size now but it's still showing up as a white image. My code looks like this now: 

`b = blockproc(dog, [8 8], @(block_struct) mean2(block_struct.data(:)) * ones(block_struct.blockSize), 'PadPartialBlocks',true);`

Comment: @MichaelChang Look at the data type of your image. Is it double or uint8? In the second case, you perform operations on small integers, and matlab handles overflow by saturating values. Try convert to double first.